# Is shared services right way to implement DRY in angular 2?

Tags: angular, codeigniter, model-view-controller, mvvm, angular2-services

I am looking for implementing ERP frontend in angular 2. I have my exisiting implementation in codeigniter HMVC structure.From which I have converted all models/controllers calls in to REST APIS.

The older structure was reusing lots of view component for CRUD operations in modules such as CRM, Accounting, Transactions etc etc.

I have doubt that is there any way to achieve the same pattern in Angular 4 with more optimization.

I have looked at shared services and it looks very promising. 
In short I am looking for correct modular structure in angular which somehow helps me to convert old HMVC codeigniter module structure.

If you need more implementation regarding new and old structure. Let me know.

Comment: Update : I come to know about service and shared components. I have lets say one instance of JSON SCHEMA FORM BUILDER inside my one component. I have to replicate it's code to develop add entry functionality for every module. Is there any way to make it shared and make it available across the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend following the Angular.io style guide for structuring an Angular application. These guidelines favor simplicity through consistent application of the LIFT principle over the traditional approach to organizing code such as grouping related components into separate folders (i.e. having a model layer, a services layer, etc). This will allow your application to  scale over time as it evolves from a very simple application with fewer than ten files to more full-featured complex applications with over hundreds or even thousands of files.

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules

Highlights:

1. Follow the LIFT principle consistently when making decisions on folder structure or file location.
2. Follow the Folders-by-Feature principle (each folder represents a feature in the Application domain, and each feature has a module which packages components, directives, pipes and services).
3. Leverage barrels (i.e. index.ts that re-exports modules, services, models, etc) from feature folders.  This will help keep the modules modular, and easier to separate modules into its own published packages later if needed.
4. Have a Core module, intended to be imported by the AppModule, whose purpose may include registering app-wide services with the root injector.  Leverage the `forRoot` and `forChild` convention to ensure services are close to the module where they are used (LIFT), while still allowing them to be registered as app-wide singletons.
5. Have one or more Shared modules, intended to be imported by Feature modules. Its purpose is to expose components, directives, and pipes that can be re-used across the application. Avoid singleton services in Shared modules (intentional singletons are Ok).
6. Be aware of deeply nested import statements - this is an obvious code smell, and a sign that you are likely violating the LIFT principle.  Re-factor your code to follow points #1-5.
7. Avoid having all models in one folder, all services in another folder, etc.  This violates LIFT and makes it more difficult to locate code related to a particular feature and challenging to separate code into re-usable packages in the future.

Here is a compliant example folder structure:

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines

Comment: Hi @pixelbits , Thanks for comprehensive guide and also link to style guide.I was looking for something like this. Now I many of my doubts are solved. I want to know one more thing that , Lets say CRUD is very common for all of my modules. Can I have some sort of service, directive  ,component or module which I can call in another components and they will create me the whole grid or add form for that component. I will pass needed argument with that calling.

Comment: This is personal preference - I would avoid creating a service for simple CRUD (http is already a service and a singleton). However, if you  need a data service that leverages or aggregates multiple HTTP requests, through RxJS operators and/or combines observables, or adds observable behaviors, then I would abstract all that behind a service.  Here are some of the interesting things you can do with observable streams: https://blog.thoughtram.io/rxjs/2017/08/24/taming-snakes-with-reactive-streams.html.  It is this kind of functionality that you would hide behind a service.